# Combining several posteriors

Tags: bayesian, posterior, stan

Is there an accepted method of combining the posterior distributions from a model fit to several participants to obtain a posterior for the entire group of participants?

The reason I am asking is that I have a Stan model, which converges very quickly without any random effects. With random effects, however, convergence takes forever.

Since I don't really have any assumptions regarding the distribution of random effects, I was wondering whether I can just obtain posteriors for all the parameters for every participant separately, and then combine the posteriors for all parameters across participants.

Comment: Maybe you could describe your data and model more precisely and possibly include Stan code for both models so we could get better idea of your problem..? Generally the two approaches you describe could lead to modeling totally different situations, so using them interchangeably could be a bad idea. Also what do you mean by "forever" - is it rather hours or weeks? Sometimes it takes long (e.g. a month non-stop).

Comment: Estimating participant-level models independently would cause you to miss out on some of the most desirable features of multilevel modeling, such as shrinkage toward the group averages.